# How to change the Bluetooth codec programatically in Kotlin, API 33?

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth, codec

**I would like to change the bluetooth codec-type from AAC to SBC. This is a very new feature, the documentation is still incomplete.** [BluetoothAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter)

I tryed the ["setCodecConfigPreference"](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/u-dp1/changes/android.bluetooth.BluetoothA2dp) but does not supported now....

```
// Manifest
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        // API 33+ ----------------------------------------------------//

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            val permissions = arrayOf(
                android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED,
                android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
            )

            if (applicationContext.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,0)
            }
            
            val device = BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_CLASSIC
            val codec = BluetoothCodecConfig.Builder()
                .setCodecType(BluetoothCodecConfig.SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_SBC)
                .build()

            
            //   HOW DO I APPLY THIS ???
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to first set up your SDK to use the Android 14 preview SDK as described [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk) (see the doc for full details):

```
android {
  compileSdkPreview "UpsideDownCake"
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    targetSdkPreview "UpsideDownCake"
  }
}
```

That should then give you access to the new APIs for Android 14, which can use by acquiring the proxy and setting the config based on a connected device:

```
context.getSystemService(BluetoothManager::class.java)
  .adapter
  .getProfileProxy(
    context,
    object : BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener {
      override fun onServiceConnected(profile: Int, proxy: BluetoothProfile) {
        (proxy as BluetoothA2dp).setCodecConfigPreference(
          bluetoothDevice,
          BluetoothCodecConfig.Builder()
            .setCodecType(BluetoothCodecConfig.SOURCE_CODEC_TYPE_SBC)
            .build()
        )
      }

      override fun onServiceDisconnected(profile: Int) {}
    },
    BluetoothProfile.A2DP
  )
```

Comment: Thank you but "setCodecConfigPreference" is unresolved reference.

Comment: Perhaps it's not intended to be a public API yet. It appears it was removed from the SDK again going from DP1 -> DP2: https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/u-dp2-incr/changes